# How to sum all unique factors in column based on group_by function in R and output as new column?

Tags: r, dataframe, group-by, dplyr

I have a dataframe that consists of 4 columns where year goes from 2016-2018 and the Lost_Reason values have a total of 15 unique "reasons" that are tallied each year:

```
Year1 LOST_REASON                   TotalLost
  <chr> <fct>                             <int>
1 2016  ""                                    0
2 2016  "Change in Business Strategy"        31
3 2016  "Data Issue"                         12
4 2016  "Lack of Adoption"                   21
5 2016  "Lack of Value"                      14
6 2016  "Lost to Competition"                20
```

How can I reformat this dataframe which was generated by this simple code:

```
df_test1 <- complete_df %>%
  mutate(full_year = format(as.Date(CLOSEDATE, format = "%m/%d/%Y"), "%Y-%m-%d")) %>%
  group_by(Year1, LOST_REASON) %>%
  summarise(TotalWon = sum(STAGENAME == 'Closed Won'), TotalLost = sum(STAGENAME == 'CS: Non-Renewal'))
```

to match an output like so where the "Lost_Reason" factors are summed per year with a "total" column generated:

```
                       Reason 2016 2017 2018 Total
1 Change in Business Strategy   31   39   45   151
2                  Data Issue   12   20   11    51
3            Lack of Adoption   21   25   26    89
4               Lack of Value   14   23   20    90
5         Lost to Competition   20   13   13    66
6                   No Budget   14   27   41   103
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be a `pivot_wider` option after creating a row index based on the 'Year' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)
df_test1 %>%
   mutate(rn = rowid(Year1)) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = Year1, values_from = TotalLost) %>%
   mutate(Total = `2016` + `2017` + `2018`)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is what I am asking for. I noticed however that my LOST_REASON column still repeats the values instead of just have a sum per level it has it 3 times (per year). In theory the output should be 15 rows instead of 25 rows

Comment: @Dinho Can you  have the `rowid(Year1, Reason)` or `rowid(Reason)` as I can't test it without your full example

Comment: I got it actually based on your code and what I had before - df_test2 <- df_test1 %>%
  #mutate(rn = rowid(Year1)) %>%
  group_by(Year1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Year1, values_from = TotalLost) %>%
  mutate(Total = `2016` + `2017` + `2018`)

Comment: @Dinho. then, where is the issue you cited earlier

Comment: I simply just grouped by year as well as used your pivot_wider method - problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

The workflow I would use is `group_by` and `summarize` to create the sum column, then `pivot_wider` to spread across the years and, finally, `left_join` to put the two together.

Note I create the sums while the data is still in "tidy" format.  You could sum across the rows after you pivot the data but that would be more complicated (for me, anyway).

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df_1 <- tribble(
  ~Year1,~LOST_REASON,~TotalLost,
  2016,  ""                                    ,0,
  2016,  "Change in Business Strategy"        ,31,
  2016,  "Data Issue"                         ,12,
  2016,  "Lack of Adoption"                   ,21,
  2016,  "Lack of Value"                      ,14,
  2016,  "Lost to Competition"                ,20,
  2017,  ""                                    ,0,
  2017,  "Change in Business Strategy"        ,31,
  2018,  "Data Issue"                         ,12,
  2019,  "Lack of Adoption"                   ,21,
  2020,  "Lack of Value"                      ,14,
  2020,  "Lost to Competition"                ,20
)

Sums <- df_1 %>% group_by(LOST_REASON) %>% 
  summarise(Sum=sum(TotalLost,na.rm = TRUE))

Sums
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   LOST_REASON                     Sum
#>   <chr>                         <dbl>
#> 1 ""                                0
#> 2 "Change in Business Strategy"    62
#> 3 "Data Issue"                     24
#> 4 "Lack of Adoption"               42
#> 5 "Lack of Value"                  28
#> 6 "Lost to Competition"            40

df_2 <- df_1 %>% pivot_wider(id_cols="LOST_REASON",
                         names_from = "Year1",
                         values_from = "TotalLost") %>% 
  left_join(Sums)
#> Joining, by = "LOST_REASON"

df_2
#> # A tibble: 6 x 7
#>   LOST_REASON                   `2016` `2017` `2018` `2019` `2020`   Sum
#>   <chr>                          <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 ""                                 0      0     NA     NA     NA     0
#> 2 "Change in Business Strategy"     31     31     NA     NA     NA    62
#> 3 "Data Issue"                      12     NA     12     NA     NA    24
#> 4 "Lack of Adoption"                21     NA     NA     21     NA    42
#> 5 "Lack of Value"                   14     NA     NA     NA     14    28
#> 6 "Lost to Competition"             20     NA     NA     NA     20    40
```

Created on 2020-04-23 by the reprex package (v0.3.0)